# extract exact links from string using Regex in swift 2.2

Tags: regex, swift, string, extract

i want extract just the links of websites following the code below:

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

func regMatchGroup(regex: String, text: String) -> [String] {
    do {
        let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: regex, options: [])
        let nsString = text as NSString
        let results = regex.matchesInString(text,
                                            options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, nsString.length))
         var internalString = [String]()
        for result in results {

            for var i = 0; i < result.numberOfRanges; ++i{
                internalString.append(nsString.substringWithRange(result.rangeAtIndex(i)))
            }
        }
        return internalString
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("invalid regex: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        return []
    }
}
// USAGE:
let textsearch = "mohamed amine ammach <img alt='http://fb.com' /> hhhhhhhhhhh <img alt='http://google.com' />"
let matches = regMatchGroup("alt='(.*?)'", text: textsearch)
if (matches.count > 0) // If we have matches....
{ 
    for (var i=0;i < matches.count;i++) {

       print(matches[i])

    }
}
```

the playgrond prints the following:

```
alt='http://fb.com'
http://fb.com
alt='http://google.com'
http://google.com
```

but i'm trying to get just:
http://fb.com
http://google.com
can anyone here help me solve this issue ?,i will be appreciated

Comment: your result is in first capturing group

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to know that `NSTextCheckingResult.rangeAtIndex(_:)` returns the range matching the whole regex pattern with index 0.

In your case:

`rangeAtIndex(0)` -> range for `alt='(.*?)'` -> `alt='http://fb.com'`

`rangeAtIndex(1)` -> range for `(.*?)` -> `http://fb.com`

So, you need to skip index value 0, when generating matching String.

Try changing inner-most for-statement to:

```
            for i in 1 ..< result.numberOfRanges { //start index from 1
                internalString.append(nsString.substringWithRange(result.rangeAtIndex(i)))
            }
```

(You need to know one more thing, that C-style for-statement is deprecated.)